# use json to graph with highcharts symfony

Tags: php, json, ajax, symfony, symfony4

How can I use the json generated from my controller to graph in the twig with highcharts?

this is my controller

```
    $sql = 'SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(fecha, \'+00:00\', 
    @@global.time_zone))*1000 as fecha, '.$n_sensor.' 
    from '.$estacion.' ';

    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $conn = $manager->getConnection();

    $result= $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll();

    $datos = array();

    foreach($result as $row){
        $datos[] = array((int)$row['fecha'],(int)$row[$n_sensor]);
    }

    $data = new Response();
    $data->setContent(json_encode($datos,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
    $data->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

and this the code of the chart I can't make it work

```
    $.getJSON('url of json', function (data) {

    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
    zoomType: 'x'
    },
    rangeSelector: {


title: {
    text: 'Humedad del sensor de suelo 1'
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Exchange rate'
    },
    /*plotBands: [{
        from: minRate,
        to: maxRate,
        color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.2)',
        label: {
            text: 'Last quarter year\'s value range'
        }

    }
    ]*/
},

series: [{
    name: 'Valor',
    data: data,
    type: 'areaspline',
    tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 0
    }
}]
});
});
```

I can a print the json in the twig with dump.
Is there any way to pass the json to the twig to use it in the graph?